# How to Build a custom simple DNS server in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, dns

I need to build a custom simple non-authoritative caching DNS server in C/C++. Any guidance? Links? Samples?

Comment: Why on Earth could you possibly need to build your own DNS server?

Comment: Cause I need a DNS server with some non standart functionality

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you look for alternate solutions, but if this is the way you have to go… djbdns is public domain, so you can hack it up all you wish.

Comment: if you're able, give some more info about this "non standard functionality".  There's several DNS specialists around here...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819993/need-to-build-simple-dns-resolver-in-c/1820254#1820254).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "simple" cacheing DNS server, particularly if you want decent security.  Recent DNS attacks have shown that the cacheing function in recursive DNS servers is particularly vulnerable.

Re-evaluate whether you actually need local cacheing of your own.  If you don't, you're probably better off modifying existing DNS proxy code (such as 'dnsmasq').

If you do want to roll-your-own, there are good libraries such as [`ldns`](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/) which can provide the access to the underlying DNS packets.

I'm using `ldns` myself in conjunction with `libevent` to implement the Fuzzing DNS server I mentioned in an earlier question.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a basic DNS server for a job interview under BSD license.

May be someone could find it useful:

https://github.com/nephewtom/dns-server

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of free software implementations of DNS. You could look at their source code. For example:

- http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html
- http://www.isc.org/products/BIND/

The book [DNS and BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575/index.html) might be helpful. And, of course, there are the RFCs that specify DNS, see http://rfc-editor.org/.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do that (it is a **huge** work, see Alnitak's reply), start from an existing **good** program (not a one-man experiment unmaintained for a long time like djbdns) and modify it.

[Unbound](http://unbound.net/) is probably a reasonable choice for this. (The code base is smaller than BIND's one.)

Comment: Note for the readers: remember to ignore downvotes if there is not a comment to explain them.

Comment: djb's software has regularly been known to behave contrary to standards because of his general belief that his way is better than the standards, and he has also been known to deny the existence of serious remote privilege elevation bugs in his code. Along with the long period during which djbdns was completely unmaintained, I think these factors make it perfectly fair for bortzmeyer to call it "a one-man experiement unmaintained for a long time" and discourage its deployment on non-hobbyist environments.

Answer (score 2):

Start with [djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html).

Comment: I would be careful about that.  djb's software has very restrictive licenses.  make sure that it agrees with your intended use.

Comment: djbdns is now public domain, but I still wouldn't use it...

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could use the [Ragel State Machine Compiler](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) to build your server from scratch.

Comment: State machine is a very small part of a server's code...

Comment: For something defined by a very strict spec like a DNS server, it's a substantial (and arguably the most important) part.