# Need To Build Simple DNS Resolver in C

Tags: c, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Build a custom simple DNS server in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649618/how-to-build-a-custom-simple-dns-server-in-c-c)

As the title says I need to build a simple dns resolver in C...

Not in C++, I have looked on internet for some tutorials to help me get going but mostly find C++.

Wondering whether anyone knows of a tutorial to get me started or can give me a couple of tips on how to build my DNS request header in C...

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for information regarding the DNS protocol itself, or just some help with networking in C?

Comment: Help with the coding of it in C... I got the information on DNS, but the actual coding of it in C is where am stuck...

Comment: Is this homework? If not, your best bet is probably to heavily "plagiarise" djbdns (or just use it). Except that it would not be plagiarism, because the source code for djbdns is in the public domain. If you're running some version of UNIX then even easier, since it will probably work unmodified.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, while you are technically correct, your terminology is somewhat disturbing. I agree, there is nothing wrong with using code in the confines of its license (or lack thereof), however claiming you wrote something that you did not is just wrong on many levels.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean Aran should make any false claims about authorship, and it would be commendable to credit DJB in the source and any attached documentation. I just mean that with djbdns you are free to: look at the code; get rid of all the stuff you maybe don't need if you're just doing a single resolution, rather than running a DNS server; copy-paste the rest; adjust if necessary; then re-distribute however you like. It's this I meant to emphasise, rather than pretending you made it all up yourself, so agreed I used the wrong term. BIND allows all but the last, but is way, way bigger code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have written a simple DNS resolver in C.

You can go about this one of three ways:

1. learn BSD socks
2. use DSNQuery
3. use gethostbyname

This example uses BSD sockets:
https://web.archive.org/web/20091206003443/https://www.binarytides.com/blog/dns-query-code-in-c-with-winsock-and-linux-sockets/

The function DSNQuery() is available in windows.  It might be overkill for what you're building.  It returns all of the resource records returned by the DNS server.
This example uses the function DSNQuery to resolve a host name:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226

This example uses gethostbyname:
http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2005/10/28/simple-gethostbyname-example/

I'd strongly recommend using an API like DNSQuery() or gethostbyname()

Comment: The binarytides one is helping a lot thanks... :-)

Comment: +1 for helping someone new to C and being very informative.