# DNS resolving in C/C++

Tags: python, c++, c, dns

In python I can work with DNS like this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dns.resolver
>>> answer = dns.resolver.query('www.example.com')
>>> print answer.response
id 37102
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
www.example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
www.example.com. 3600 IN A 93.184.216.34
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
>>> print answer.rrset
www.example.com. 3600 IN A 93.184.216.34
>>>
```

What's the easiest way to achieve the same result in C/C++? Either using a library (which one most popular?) or sending the request manuall via sockets or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649618/how-to-build-a-custom-simple-dns-server-in-c-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328093/dns-lookup-in-c-c

Answer (score 3):

Start with [getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo).  Then the [res_* functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/resolver) for advanced queries.  These other functions might be useful to you as well.

[gethostbyname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname)

[getnameinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo)

[gethostent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostent)

Comment: well, is that the easies way - requesting by sockets, manually? Or maybe should I use a library which works with DNS instead?

Comment: Those functions are your library.  If you just want IP address resolution start with gethostbyname or getaddrinfo.  If you want a finer grain control of the query and to get access to the full response back, use the res_ functions.  That python library you reference is likely using those exact same functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getaddrinfo`.The getaddrinfo function provides protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address.
as for The `gethostbyname` function, it retrieves host information corresponding to a host name from a host database.
like our friend selbie said, the res_*functions are used for advanced Queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use libraries for DNS in C++:

**Linux**

> [GNU adns](http://www.gnu.org/software/adns/)

**Windows** (Read the answers of this post)

> [Where can I find a C++ DNS Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755023/where-can-i-find-a-c-dns-library)